# How can I organize variant building of a parametrized job in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I have a parametrized job that takes a name, a SVN Repository and a shared directory. I need to call this job regularly with roughly 20 sets of these parameters. At the moment I just created 20 jobs and each calls the main job.

This is a very tedious configuration and clutters the main view in Jenkins.

Is there a better possibility to solve this? I am open to either restructure the jobs or use plugins to "hide" them.

---

More Details about the jobs:
I have actually two kinds of main jobs:

- a delivery job. We deploy our application to ~20 different shared directories. These jobs are configured to run once every night. (Trigger build periodically)
- a computation job. This one computes data based on the svn repository and stores it in the shared directory. These jobs are configured to run every 15 minutes.
- The jobs may and should run in parallel

What I need/want:

- Sometimes it is needed that a developer needs to start one (or a couple) of the configurations manually
- Something like the matrix configuration plugin could solve my problem. If it would be possible to somehow set my parameters as one axis, I would be happy
- Multijob would be another close solution to my problem, unfortunately this 'bug' blocks me: [JENKINS-39678](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39678)

Comment: are you doing deployments? :) is it just you running these 20 combinations? could you make somewhere between 1 and 20 bash functions (depending on how many parameters make sense) that trigger the (one) main jenkins job via the API?

Comment: Also what should be triggering the different jobs? Are they run manually,  cron, etc?

Comment: I have added some additional information. @burnettk That could work, I fear that this buries the configuration deep inside a job and makes it hard to call one specific configuration.

Comment: @Morfic The builds are triggered directly from jenkins: Trigger periodically

Comment: Depending on what you can or can't do, the simplest idea that comes to mind is to keep the current configuration but [change the `All` view with a custom one](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Editing+or+Replacing+the+All+View) that displays only your main job(s). Alternatively you could replace all the jobs with a [multi-job](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) (or a similar pipeline) creating a phase for each current job. Unfortunately I did not see a way to execute an individual phase... Take a look and let us know if you see any issues with the approaches.

Comment: @Morfic thanks for the ideas. Multijob is pretty close to what I'm looking for, unfortunately it fails when calling one job multiple times. It does not correctly distinguish the calls and it is not possible to give them separate names. Additionally phases are not parallel, my jobs can and should be. Replacing the All view keeps my current configuration I would still have to handle a couple of loosely coupled jobs in a different view.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can give a different name to each phase (that is if you have as many separate phases as your old projects, not all of them under the same phase), but I'm not entirely sure about parallelism, I'll take a look tomorrow. Meanwhile you could take a shot a [pipelines](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) ([parallel-job-example](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/#jobs-in-parallel), [parallelism-and-distributed-jobs](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/parallelism-and-distributed-builds-jenkins))

Comment: @Morfic Phases are not parallel. "Phases are used to execute many jobs in parallel, whilst Phases are sequential." I have some concerns with pipelines 1) I'm burying the configuration deep in a job 2) I can't trigger one of these jobs alone, can I? 3) I'm not sure if it will be easy to see which job failed and just restart that one.

Comment: I'm starting to think that my approach is completely uncommon as there are suspicious few good solutions to this. Do you all think I took a wrong turn somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Not allowed to comment, but @Absurd-Mind, it sounds like you wanted to build just one job in the beginning that fits all and blows up now. When you have about 20 different settings try to find a larger common basis or split them completely.

Also, we have also such a job.... old shell script crap and well, one of my colleagues build a **multijob** pipeline around it, that **can run in parallel**. Under MultiJob Phase you can set Job execution to parallel.

But be careful, if it contains a build tool like bower or so you can't as easily wipe the cache because they share one.

Comment: The main job has roughly 100 lines of bash scripts and also multiple downstream jobs. This is the common part. the difference between the 20 jobs are three strings: 'name', 'svnRepo', 'path'. I do not see how I could move one of these strings into the main job. Splitting them completely would duplicate a lot of configuration and doesn't seem feasible. In your second half, do you mean the multijob plugin?

Comment: Yes, I did. Ok, that's really not a big difference. Maybe theultijob plugin help. We're also just calling another job multiple times with different parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Pipeline plugin and write groovy code to do this. You could add a bunch of checkbox input parameters, 1 for each set of parameters you want, and then conditionally execute the other job with that set of parameters.

[image: image of build parameters with checkboxes]

```
node: {
   stage ('set1') {
      if(env.build_set1) {
         build job: 'main_job', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'name', value: 'Name1'], [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'directory', value: 'dir1']]
      }
   }

   stage ('set2') {
      if(env.build_set2) {
         build job: 'main_job', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'name', value: 'Name2'], [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'directory', value: 'dir2']]
      }
   }
}
```

This example runs sequentially, but you can also [make these jobs run in parallel](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/#jobs-in-parallel).

Comment: I have some concerns with this solution: 1) I'm burying the configuration of my jobs very deep inside the pipeline, it will become hard to understand/maintain 2) the parameter and the 'if' are only loosely coupled, detecting errors will become hard 3) It becomes hard identifying the failing job 4) restarting a failed stage becomes unhandy (at the moment I just need to press the rebuild button) 5) handling of errors will become clumsy (try/catch around every stage): stage1 should not stop stage2; Using the matrix-configuration plugin would make it better, but then the pipeline has no meaning...

Comment: I understand #1, its code, you have to dig into the config, although you can refactor so all jobs are declared up top in an object list and the ugly stuff goes in a loop with error handling. Not sure I see why its hard to identify a failing job, as the status and log output of each stage are clearly displayed. As for #4 you can use a ```checkpoint``` before each stage, which allows you to run that particular stage again with a button click... unfortunately it seems its [only available in the enterprise version](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33846).

Comment: I was not aware of the fact that you can have parallel stages. Still not being able to start a pipeline at one specific stage is a bummer